# Custom report, regex - filter for results only from specific websites/urls containing keywords

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, report

I created a custom report in Google Analytics which I want to filter so that I see only the results/activities that come from predefined sub-websites including specific keywords e.g. I want to see results only from urls which include (/xy/abc) and (/xy/xyz) after the domain. I tried multiple ways but I am hopelessly stuck.

I have been working with "Hostname" and "Page" to then apply different exact paths and regex versions e.g. /xy/(abc|xyz)/.* or /xy/abc|xy/xyz but non worked. [abc] returned some interesting results. When I do [def] and [ghi] I get the same results for both when they should return different activities.

Please help.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of text that you want to match, and text that you don't want to match?
Which flavor of regex are you using, javascript?

Comment: Try `^xy/(?:abc|xyz)(?:/|$)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the above did not return any results. However "abc|xyz" did, although I expected other results which brings me back to my initial question. Anyway, I realized that all of the URLs which do not show up in the Google Analytics report also do not show up in the underlying sitemap.

Assuming I do things right with Regex and GA, could it be that if one of the two URLs containing e.g. "abc" does not show up in the sitemap and ergo not in the GA report, that the error lies with the sitemap and the guys who set it up (in-house, no clue how they built the websites and sitemap)?